# Deeplink is only working with custom scheme not HTTPS

Tags: ionic-framework, https, deep-linking

I´m currently working with Ionic 5 and trying to add a deeplink functionality for activating and account or resetting a password.
My current solution is working in general but only with my custom scheme but not with HTTPS. Maybe I got something wrong but I want the user to click on an HTTPS link which comes in via mail and open the app instead of the browser with Https. I tested in a codepen and it´s working with **myScheme://myurl.com/user/activate?link={linkGuid}** but not with **[https://myurl.com/user/activate?link={linkGuid}](https://myurl.com/user/activate?link=%7BlinkGuid%7D)**.

Here is my config.xml:

```
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-deeplinks" spec="1.0.24">
    <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="myScheme" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_SCHEME" value="https" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_HOST" value="myurl.com" />
</plugin>
```

Any ideas what I could try to make it work?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers!

Comment: Did u try to reinstall the app since maybe its still saved in the device as the default it was registered with "http"...

Comment: Well, https does not work but http surprisingly does! I just reinstalled the app but it´s still not working with https. Do you know what could cause the problem?